# Visual NUnit and App.config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

I'm using the Visual NUnit runner for VS.NET 2010 and am unable to get it read my app.config file.  I've seen posts online about coping the VisualNunitRunner.exe.config file to the project folder but my app is still unable to load a configuration section from the config.  Has anyone run into this problem that can explain the specific steps to resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: probably restarting your visual studio will solve the problem??

Comment: Tried that.  I'm still confused as to where exactly I'm supposed to copy the file...the project folder with "Copy To Output Directory" set to true?  Am I supposed to put my application config settings in this file or still a second file with my settings (such as [Assembly Name].config)?  I've tried both with no success.